# Querying for Consecutive Rows with Certain Characteristics

Tags: sql, mysql

I've got a table with the following columns:

```
id int(10)
user int(10)
winner int(10)
profit double
created datetime
```

The winner column can be either 0 or 1.  I'd like to create a query that returns the maximum number of consecutive winners as ordered by the created datetime column along with the first and last created date as well as the sum of the profit column from that period of consecutive winners.

Comment: Are you looking for consecutive winners with the same user? Or just consecutive wins?

Comment: Either one, but hopefully the solution can implement either one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a possible solution that looks at winning streaks per userid.

```
select head.userid, head.id, sum(profit), count(*)
from #bingo b
inner join (
    select cur.userid, cur.id
    from #bingo cur
    left join #bingo prev 
        on cur.userid = prev.userid
        and prev.id < cur.id
        and not exists(
            select * 
            from #bingo inbetween 
            where prev.userid = inbetween.userid 
            and prev.id < inbetween.id 
            and inbetween.id < cur.id)
    where cur.winner = 1
    and IsNull(prev.winner,0) = 0
) head
    on head.userid = b.userid 
    and head.id <= b.id
```

```
left join (
    select cur.userid, cur.id
    from #bingo cur
    left join #bingo prev 
        on cur.userid = prev.userid
        and prev.id < cur.id
        and not exists(
            select * 
            from #bingo inbetween 
            where prev.userid = inbetween.userid 
            and prev.id < inbetween.id 
            and inbetween.id < cur.id)
    where cur.winner = 1
    and IsNull(prev.winner,0) = 0
) nexthead 
    on nexthead.userid = b.userid 
    and head.id < nexthead.id 
    and nexthead.id <= b.id
where nexthead.id is null 
and b.winner = 1
group by head.userid, head.id
```

The two "heads" subqueries are identical, you could put them in a view or a WITH where those are supported.  The "heads" subquery searches for each head of a winning streak; that is, the first win or a win that's preceeded by a loss.  I'm assuming your id's increase over time, so I'm not using the Created column.

The query below that searches the corresponding head for every row.  A head's id must be smaller or equal to the current row's id, and there must be no other head in between.

After that it's a simple matter of grouping on the head, and summing the profits and counting the rows.

Comment: I see what you're getting at but I'm using mysql and it doesn't like the with statement: ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'with heads as ("

Comment: Rewritten without WITH now. For performance, check if you have a primary key on id, and an index on userid

Comment: `IsNull(prev.winner,0) = 0` doesn't work that way in mySQL. It could be rewritten to mySQL as `IsNull(prev.winner) = 1` instead.

Comment: I tried to do this on a table with 2 million rows, it basically took too long time for me to wait for the result.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested it but maybe this will work.

```
    select first_winner.created, last_winner.created, sum(mid_winner.profit)
          from T first_winner
     join T last_winner
          on first_winner.created <= last_winner.created
          and first_winner.winner = 1
          and last_winner.winner = 1
          and not exists -- no losers in between first_winner and last_winner
          (
           select * from T loser
           where loser.winner = 0
            and first_winner.created <= loser.created 
                                    and loser.created <= last_winner.created
          )
     join T mid_winner
          on first_winner.created <= mid_winner.created
                                 and mid_winner.created <= last_winner.created
          and mid_winner.winner = 1
     left join T bef_first_winner  -- winner before first winner with no losers in between
          on bef_first_winner.winner = 1
          and bef_first_winner.created < first_winner.created
          and not exists
          ( 
           select * from T b_loser
           where b_loser.winner = 0
            and bef_first_winner.created <= b_loser.created 
               and b_loser.created <= first_winner.created
          )
     left join T after_last_winner -- winner after last winner with no losers in between
          on after_last_winner.winner = 1
          and last_winner.created < after_last_winner.created
          and not exists
          ( 
           select * from T a_loser
           where a_loser.winner = 0
            and last_winner.created <= a_loser.created 
               and a_loser.created <= after_last_winner.created
          )
    where bef_first_winner.id is null
        and after_last_winner.id is null
   group by first_winner.created, last_winner.created
```

Comment: I get: "ERROR 1140 (42000): Mixing of GROUP columns (MIN(),MAX(),COUNT(),...) with no GROUP columns is illegal if there is no GROUP BY clause"

Comment: sorry, I forgot the group clause

Comment: I executed it and it's still running.  Been a couple hours now.  ;-)